# Object C to Swift custom class implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, class

I am using a library `GTImageDraw` that allows drawing on image and having it saved. As I am going to modify it quite a fair bit, I'd like to change it to swift as I am more familiar with swift language. I am stuck at the beginning.

At the header file of `GTImageDraw` it consists of

```
@interface UIView (Draw)
- (void)startDrawing;
-(void)stopDrawing;
-(void)resetImage;
-(void)setBrush:(CGFloat) b;
-(void) setColor:(UIColor *) color;
- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage;
-(UIImage*) save;
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(void)selectRubber;
@end
```

At the `.m` file of `GTImageDraw`, it consists of

```
@implementation UIImageView (Draw)
```

I tried to create a `draw.swift` file and added

```
class Draw: UIImageView {}
```

This is obviously not right because I imagine I will need to declare `UIView` somewhere like the header file. It is also complain that I don't have initialize. However, in the `.m` or `.h` file, there is no init method anywhere.

I am a bit new to all this. Thanks for helping

---

[Question update]
How about the variables that was declared initially in the `.m` file

```
@implementation UIImageView (Draw)

UIImage *mainImg;
UIImageView *mainImageView;

BOOL _isErasing = NO;
BOOL activate = NO;
CGPoint lastPoint;
CGFloat red = 0.0/255.0;
CGFloat green = 0.0/255.0;
CGFloat blue = 0.0/255.0;
CGFloat brush = 5.0;
CGFloat opacity = 1.0;
BOOL mouseSwiped;

-(void)startDrawing{

}
```

I couldn't do the following as declaration of variable is not allowed in extension

```
extension UIView {

    let mainImg: UIImage
    let mainImageView: UIImageView

    let _isErasing: Bool = false
    let activate: Bool = false

    let lastPoint: CGPoint
    let red: CGFloat = 0.0/255.0
    let green: CGFloat = 0.0/255.0
    let blue: CGFloat = 0.0/255.0
    let brush: CGFloat = 5.0
    let opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
    let mouseSwiped: Bool

}
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In the Objective-C code you showed, you have a category, not a class implementation. The Swift equivalent is

```
extension UIView {
    func startDrawing() {
        // …
    }

    func stopDrawing() {
        // …
    }

    func resetImage() {
        // …
    }

    func setBrush(b: CGFloat) {
        // …
    }

    func setColor(color: UIColor) {
        // …
    }

    func imageByCombining(firstImage: UIImage, withSecondImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    }

    // etc.
}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
let view = UIView()

view.setColor(UIColor.orangeColor())
view.startDrawing()
view.stopDrawing()
```

Comment: Thanks Aarron. That was fast! Please see Question update as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The code is now converted to swift with the following implementation:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

private var _isErasing:Bool = false
private var activate: Bool = false
private var mouseSwiped: Bool = false
private var red: CGFloat = 0.0/255.0
private var green: CGFloat = 0.0/255.0
private var blue: CGFloat = 0.0/255.0
private var brush: CGFloat = 5.0
private var opacity: CGFloat = 1.0
private var mainImg = UIImage()
private var mainImageView = UIImageView()
private var lastPoint = CGPoint()

extension UIImageView {

    public func _startDrawing() {
}
```

Not sure why the interface uses UIView instead of UIImageView though.